# Is it safe to use Popcorn Time?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Linux and I want to know if it's safe to install Popcorn Time from [here](https://popcorntime.io/)?

---

After `popcorn/install`

I see:

```
Popcorn Time 0.3.8-0 - Linux 32 bits
==================================

Please read our Terms of service:
        https://popcorntime.io/tos

This installer will install Popcorn Time in:
        ~/.Popcorn-Time
        ~/.local/share/applications
        ~/.local/share/icons

To continue, type 'I agree': I agree
```

After I type "I agree", I see:

```
Popcorn Time 0.3.8-0 - Linux 32 bits
==================================

- Copying files to ~/.Popcorn-Time

Unexpected Error:
=================
at: 1: Copy files
... Please try again.
```

Tell me please should I be logged in as root on the system to install and use it afterwards?

Comment: Not really an Ubuntu issue. https://popcorntime.io/faq

Comment: Probably not more or less than on any other platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Popcorn Time* from [popcorntime.io](http://popcorntime.io) (not be confused with the one at popcorn-time.se) does not cause any stability issues for your system. This is a non-system app that should not harm the overall health of your system.

There are other *issues* however. The app downloads **torrent** of **copyrighted** material and this is certainly *illegal* in your country. You might be legally **liable**. This could mean fine, or penalty under the strike system, or jail (?). You have been warned. ;-)

[There is a PPA for PopcornTime at webupd8](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/popcorntime)

You can run in a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/popcorntime
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install popcorn-time
```

Comment: Thank you @solsTiCe, tell me please for installing on this way as you recommended, and use it afterwards it will ask for any root privileges?  I am asking this because http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2286343&p=13319103#post13319103 Thank you.

Comment: You need root to install the app but afterwards there is no need for root anymore.

Comment: are there any differences as stability/speed or any other differences to use it without installing only accessing the executable file "Popcorn-Time" after unpacking Popcorn-Time-0.3.8-0-Linux-32.tar.xz. After using in this way(without installing) For example I saw that the subtitles settings remain after closing it... what other differences could be?

Comment: The answer is: none

Comment: Tell me please, on that way(without installing) does it use/access any root privileges of the system?

Answer (score 1):

Other than the fact that it uses torrents, Popcorn Times is harmless. It will not make your system unstable or cause any security risk.

Since you are a new linux user go ahead and download the package from the official [website](https://popcorntime.io/).

Open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and the navigate to the folder where you've downloaded the package (most probably your `Downloads` directory:

```
cd Downloads
```

Create a directory called `popcorn` and unpack the contents of the downloaded package (`Popcorn-Time-0.3.8-0-Linux-32.tar.xz` or similar):

```
mkdir popcorn
tar xvf Popcorn-Time-0.3.8-0-Linux-32.tar.xz -C popcorn
```

Now, type the following and follow the onscreen instructions to install popcorn:

```
popcorn/install
```

A desktop entry will be created.